# Java Discord API commands printing nothing

Tags: java, discord, bots, discord-jda

So I am extremely new to this JDA library but I am well-versed in Java. I just can't seem to find out why the following code does not work. I have a Init class and a commands class.

**Init class**:

```
package corp.vjz.bots.discord.testbot;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.OnlineStatus;


public class Initialize {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        
        //starts the discord robot
        JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("NzIyMTMyNjczOTkyMzI3MzEw.Xueodg.EpeszQDFxc1IM21_CZmKMUv7Wys").build();
        
        //sets the status of the discord robot
        jda.getPresence().setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE);
        
        //add a new event listener
        jda.addEventListener(new Commands());
    }
}
```

Here is my commands class:

```
package corp.vjz.bots.discord.testbot;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;


public class Commands extends ListenerAdapter {
    
    private static String PREFIX = "-";
    
    public void onGuildMsgReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        
        //parse through message
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Commands.PREFIX + "info")) {
            event.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Wassup! BRO.").queue();
            
        }
    }
}
```

This should say "Wassup! BRO." whenever a user chats "-info" but in reality, nothing shows up. And yes I did invite the discord bot and did the Oauth2 and whatever, that end is fine, just I don't know why its not printing what it should print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't override the method from ListenerAdapter. To quote from [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19)-Troubleshooting#my-event-listener-code-is-not-executed):

> **4. You did not override the correct method?**
> Use `@Override` and see if it fails. Your method has to use the correct name and parameter list defined in ListenerAdapter. [Read More.](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/1%29-Events)

So the right method name is documented in the [ListenerAdapter javadoc](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/hooks/ListenerAdapter.html#method.summary) which is `onGuildMessageReceived`.

Answer (score -1):

you didn't write the else code for the if command;